# How to plot data in form of gauge using python without plotly as I have to do offline?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data that I need to plot as a gauge/meter. I cannot use `plotly` as it works only online.

Comment: Needs clarification. Are you working on a web-app?

Comment: Plotly can also work offline. Apart the question is really too broad.

Comment: No it’s not a web app, it’s a desktop program.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by a "gauge/meter". If you just to fill an area to a given percentage, take a look at [`broken_barh`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.broken_barh.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.broken_barh) for an horizontal gauge. If you want a vertical one, you will have to do it yourself:

- create an axis with y limits (0, 100) and x limits (0, 1)
- draw a rectangle from (0, 0) to (value, 1)

If you want some more fancy stuff, I just found [an example](http://nicolasfauchereau.github.io/climatecode/posts/drawing-a-gauge-with-matplotlib/) which seems to match the `plotly` style.